# Obtain a property from all colors in Xamarin.Forms.Color

Tags: xamarin, reflection

Let's say I want to obtain the"R" component from all Colors in Xamarin.Forms.Color. I tried this:

`var RComponentList = typeof(Color).GetRuntimeFields().
         Select((f) => f.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("R"));`

but the result is a list of nulls. Is like it managed to find the colors but not the "R" property in each of them. How can I achieve this ?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fields = typeof(Color).GetRuntimeFields()
    .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(Color) && x.IsInitOnly)
    .Select(x => ((Color)x.GetValue(null)).R);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Will Decker for his answer. What I wanted to achieve was to obtain the name of all the colors and their RGB values. Finally I did this:

```
 private void PopulateColorsList()
    {
        _colors = new Dictionary<string, (double R, double G, double B)>();
            foreach (var c in typeof(Color).GetRuntimeFields().Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Color) && f.IsInitOnly))
            {
                var color = ((Color)c.GetValue(null));
                _colors.Add(c.Name, (color.R, color.G, color.B));
            }
        }
    }
```